# How to run PhantomJS on CentOS with SELinux?

Tags: centos, httpd, selinux, phantomjs

I'm trying to make a screenshot using PhantomJS on my CentOS 5 machine, but I can't get it to work together with SELinux. It works on an identical machine with SELinux disabled, so I really suspect that SELinux is responsible for this.

Here's what I've tried (all commands were run as root), and the errors that I got:

```
$ ls -Z /usr/local/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.6.2-linux-x86_64-dynamic/bin

-rwxr-xr-x  myusername myusername system_u:object_r:bin_t          phantomjs
```

Tried screenshot - failed

```
$ cat /var/log/messages | grep avc

Sep 13 12:21:18 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531678.014:398): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=6842 comm="sh" path="/sbin/ldconfig" dev=dm-0 ino=3097762 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ldconfig_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:21:18 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531678.014:399): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=6842 comm="sh" path="/sbin/ldconfig" dev=dm-0 ino=3097762 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ldconfig_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:21:18 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531678.054:400): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=6852 comm="sh" path="/sbin/ldconfig" dev=dm-0 ino=3097762 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ldconfig_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:21:18 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531678.054:401): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=6852 comm="sh" path="/sbin/ldconfig" dev=dm-0 ino=3097762 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ldconfig_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:21:19 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531679.866:402): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=6864 comm="sh" path="/sbin/ldconfig" dev=dm-0 ino=3097762 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ldconfig_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:21:19 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531679.867:403): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=6864 comm="sh" path="/sbin/ldconfig" dev=dm-0 ino=3097762 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ldconfig_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:21:19 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531679.920:404): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=6874 comm="sh" path="/sbin/ldconfig" dev=dm-0 ino=3097762 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ldconfig_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:21:19 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531679.920:405): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=6874 comm="sh" path="/sbin/ldconfig" dev=dm-0 ino=3097762 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:ldconfig_exec_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:21:27 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531687.025:406): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=6890 comm="phantomjs" name="3830d5c3ddfd5cd38a049b759396e72e-x86-64.cache-2" dev=dm-0 ino=2021753 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:21:27 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531687.035:407): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=6890 comm="phantomjs" name="myusername" dev=dm-0 ino=619658 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=user_u:object_r:user_home_dir_t:s0 tclass=dir
Sep 13 12:21:27 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531687.061:408): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=6890 comm="phantomjs" name="e3ead4b767b8819993a6fa3ae306afa9-x86-64.cache-2" dev=dm-0 ino=2021752 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:var_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:21:28 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531688.720:410): avc:  denied  { execmem } for  pid=6890 comm="phantomjs" scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=process
```

Tried changing type of phantomjs to httpd_sys_script_exec_t

```
$ chcon -v -t httpd_sys_script_exec_t /usr/local/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.6.2-linux-x86_64-dynamic/bin/phantomjs

$ ls -Z /usr/local/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.6.2-linux-x86_64-dynamic/bin

-rwxr-xr-x  myusername myusername system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_exec_t phantomjs
```

Retried screenshot - failed

```
$ cat /var/log/messages | grep avc

Sep 13 12:26:05 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531965.891:414): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=6962 comm="phantomjs" path="eventpoll:[9737788]" dev=eventpollfs ino=9737788 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:26:05 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531965.892:415): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=6962 comm="phantomjs" path=2F7661722F72756E2F777367692E363535352E302E312E6C6F636B202864656C6574656429 dev=dm-0 ino=2022252 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:26:05 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531965.892:416): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=6962 comm="phantomjs" path=2F7661722F72756E2F777367692E363535352E302E322E6C6F636B202864656C6574656429 dev=dm-0 ino=2022255 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:26:05 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531965.892:417): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=6962 comm="phantomjs" path=2F7661722F72756E2F777367692E363535352E302E332E6C6F636B202864656C6574656429 dev=dm-0 ino=2022257 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0 tclass=file
Sep 13 12:26:05 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347531965.893:418): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=6962 comm="phantomjs" path=2F7661722F72756E2F777367692E363535352E302E342E6C6F636B202864656C6574656429 dev=dm-0 ino=2022266 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_sys_script_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0 tclass=file
```

Tried changing type of phantomjs to httpd_t

```
$ chcon -v -t httpd_t /usr/local/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.6.2-linux-x86_64-dynamic/bin/phantomjs

failed to change context of /usr/local/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.6.2-linux-x86_64-dynamic/bin/phantomjs to system_u:object_r:httpd_t
chcon: failed to change context of /usr/local/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.6.2-linux-x86_64-dynamic/bin/phantomjs to system_u:object_r:httpd_t: Permission denied
```

Tried changing type of phantomjs to httpd_var_run_t

```
$ chcon -v -t httpd_var_run_t /usr/local/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.6.2-linux-x86_64-dynamic/bin/phantomjs

$ ls -Z /usr/local/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.6.2-linux-x86_64-dynamic/bin

-rwxr-xr-x  myusername myusername system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t phantomjs
```

Retried screenshot - failed

```
$ cat /var/log/messages | grep avc

Sep 13 12:29:36 myserver kernel: type=1400 audit(1347532176.754:420): avc:  denied  { execute } for  pid=7002 comm="httpd" name="phantomjs" dev=dm-0 ino=3032985 scontext=system_u:system_r:httpd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:httpd_var_run_t:s0 tclass=file
```

Tried changing type of phantomjs to httpd_sys_script_t

```
$ chcon -v -t httpd_sys_script_t /usr/local/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.6.2-linux-x86_64-dynamic/bin/phantomjs

failed to change context of /usr/local/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.6.2-linux-x86_64-dynamic/bin/phantomjs to system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_t
chcon: failed to change context of /usr/local/phantomjs/phantomjs-1.6.2-linux-x86_64-dynamic/bin/phantomjs to system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_script_t: Permission denied
```

Here's some more information regarding my SELinux setup:

```
$ sestatus

SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 21
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

...

```
$ getsebool -a | grep http

allow_httpd_anon_write --> off
allow_httpd_bugzilla_script_anon_write --> off
allow_httpd_cvs_script_anon_write --> off
allow_httpd_mod_auth_pam --> off
allow_httpd_nagios_script_anon_write --> off
allow_httpd_prewikka_script_anon_write --> off
allow_httpd_squid_script_anon_write --> off
allow_httpd_sys_script_anon_write --> off
httpd_builtin_scripting --> on
httpd_can_network_connect --> off
httpd_can_network_connect_db --> off
httpd_can_network_relay --> off
httpd_can_sendmail --> on
httpd_disable_trans --> off
httpd_enable_cgi --> on
httpd_enable_ftp_server --> off
httpd_enable_homedirs --> on
httpd_execmem --> off
httpd_read_user_content --> off
httpd_rotatelogs_disable_trans --> off
httpd_setrlimit --> off
httpd_ssi_exec --> off
httpd_suexec_disable_trans --> off
httpd_tty_comm --> on
httpd_unified --> on
httpd_use_cifs --> off
httpd_use_nfs --> off
```

...

```
$ uname -r

2.6.18-308.1.1.el5
```

Does anyone with SELinux / httpd experience know if there is a context that's a good match for what I'm trying to do? Or maybe I should bite the bullet and build some custom policy for this?

Comment: Disable selinux?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a very constructive solution. That way I would throw out the baby with the bath water don't you think?

Comment: "so I really suspect that SELinux is responsible for this" -> You would make sure about that by disabling selinux.

Comment: Ah, that's what you meant :) I'll try that

Comment: I tried disabling SELinux using 'setenforce 0', and then it works, so SELinux is definitely the cause

Comment: It sounds like you are going to have to create a custom policy

Answer (score 5):

Here's some snippets from [http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#7](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/SELinux#head-faa96b3fdd922004cdb988c1989e56191c257c01) on how to create a custom policy module with `allow2audit`.

Try it

```
setenforce 0
grep phantomjs /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -m httpd_phantomjs > httpd_phantomjs.te
cat httpd_phantomjs.te
```

Install it

```
grep phantomjs /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M httpd_phantomjs
semodule -i httpd_phantomjs.pp
ls /etc/selinux/targeted/modules/active/modules/ | grep httpd
```

Test it

```
setenforce 1
tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log
```

This is untested so please update as necessary. Hope it works for you

Comment: And if you don't have audit2allow, you might need to [install it](http://blog.centralserv.co.uk/how-to-use-selinux-on-centos-6-5/).

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same problem and managed to get phantom working on Centos 7.4 without having to create a custom policy. Here's how I did it.

Update selinux policy by changing phantomjs file to `bin_t` type
`semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t '/opt/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs'`

After adding new type to selinux policy you need to update the file permissions
`sudo /sbin/restorecon -v /opt/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs`

Now you need to allow httpd daemon to change its resource limits by setting the boolean

`sudo setsebool -P httpd_setrlimit 1`

Hope it helps :)